# Present USE flags upon emerging a package in gentoo

Tags: package-management, compiling, gentoo, emerge

I was wondering if there are any tools to present the compile time options/ flags of a package in Gentoo when emerging. I am referring to something like [this](http://files.cyberciti.biz/uploads/faq/2008/10/freebsd-nginx-install-options.png)

Comment: Really ? Setting USE flags for different package is standard configuration of portage, did you read about its manual ? By placing some files in /etc/portage/XX.d/ (can't remember the name now), you overwide /etc/make.conf

Answer (score 4):

`emerge gentoolkit`

Then `equery u CATEGORY/PKG` will give you the USE flags for `CATEGORY/PKG`, it will show the flags available (and to be used according to your USE settings) as well as the flags actually used for any packages already installed. Useful if you need to remember what was used for an installed package.

If you then run the command `euse -E FLAG` or `euse -D FLAG` you can enable or disable FLAG globally. As mentinoed in another comment `flaggie` can adjust `/etc/portage/package.use`, but you shouldn't need to touch that often; you would want to avoid adding something a hundred times that could just be set globally.

Comment: equery will show the flags available (and to be used according to your USE settings) as well as the flags actually used for any packages already installed.  Useful if you need to remember what was used for an installed package.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at app-portage/ufed.

Comment: Thanks. Can ufed be used per package to set the USE flags?

Comment: Sorry, ufed is used to edit the system wide flags :/

Comment: :-( That's sad. It would be cool in my mind to have such a tool.

Answer (score 1):

Use `emerge -av ...` and it will display you a list of packages to be merged, including the USE flags.

To *set* the USE flags for a package either use `/etc/portage/package.use` or a tool like `flaggie` that does the job for you.